# Handling different XSD versions when binding XML to Java classes

Tags: java, xml, data-binding, jaxb, xsd

I want to be able to expose an object that represents an XML file to my users. This can be done with many libraries (xmlBeans, JAXB...) and it's all well and fine until I have to support different versions of that XML file (evolving schema problem) for backward compatibility.

I want this to be completely transparent to my users, meaning it is my system that needs to decide which which version of XML file needs to be used at a certain point in time.

Here's a short pseudo code of what I want to achieve:

```
public VersionIndependantObject getVersionSpecificXmlBindedObject() {
    //Determening XSD version and binding XML file to JAVA object
    return javaObject;
}
```

VersionIndependantObject - this is an object representation of XML file found on the system at that time (it could be v1,v2...).

Is there a way of doing with one of an already existing libraries for XML -> Java Object binding?

Comment: A few questions:  How different are your versions of the XML Schema?  Can the latest version support all previous versions?  Do you include a version attribute in root element of your XML document?  Do you keep the namespace the same?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I can't really know how different the schemas will be as it is not me who defines them but an external system.

I can, however, differentiate them by a version of that system

Comment: It seems to me that you have two problems and are seeking one solution. You have to decompose the problems and solve each one separately. One problem is already solved. The other problem you might be able to solve by delegating the validation process. Some sort of "validator" will determine the version and will then load the appropriate processor classes to handle it. I suggest to look into behavioral design patterns for a possible solution. Template and Mediator do come to mind. A structural design patter such as Adapter pattern might also work.

Answer (score 3):

### XML Schema is Backwards Compatible

Often times XML schemas will evolve so that that they are backwards compatible.  This is done by only adding new attributes and elements that are optional.  This means an old XML document will still be valid against the new schema.  When this strategy is used you simply need to regenerate the model against the new XML schema.

### XML Schema is Not Backwards Compatible

If the model is not backwards compatable then things are more complicated.

**Generating the Model**

You could generate a model for each version of the XML schema.  If the namespace doesn't change you will need to override the default package name.

**Unmarshalling**

The instead of unmarshalling the XML directly you could parse it with a StAX parser.  Then you can use the `XMLStreamReader` to get the version attribute and determine the model to be used.  Then unmarshal the `XMLStreamReader` into that model.

---

### UPDATE

> I've already done that (the logic behind which model to use when
>   unmarshaling part is a bit different though). the problem is
>   transparency towards the user (return type). It's not until runtime
>   that I know which model will be returned. How would you handle that?

You either need to have a generic return type (i.e. `Object`) that can be of any of the generated models, or like in your question have version specific methods that each return their corresponding generated model. I would investigate what schema evolution strategy is being used. Many people try to be backwards friendly (since it helps their processing too).

Comment: I've already done that (the logic behind which model to use when unmarshaling part is a bit different though). 

the problem is transparency towards the user (return type). It's not until runtime that I know which model will be returned.

How would you handle that?

Comment: I was thinking about something like this: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/01/mapping_the_sam.html

but i guess he had other ideas to work on ;)

Comment: @esper - Here are a couple things we did in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) that you may find helpful http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html and http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-inputoutput-partial.html

Comment: some interesting articles you've linked me through there... Does it all have to be done manually or there is some automatic object generation that could happen here?

Comment: @esper - The mapping document and object graphs need to be created manually.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan can u please explain how to handle behind which model to use using just jaxb and sax parser